# How can I create a business rule in Master Data Services that would force all lowercase in the attributes?

Tags: regex, mds

I am looking to create a business rule in Master Data Services that would force all entries in an attribute to be lowercase.  Is there a way to do this possibly with Regex or any other method?  Thanks.